# Setting up Authlogic I keep hitting: "undefined method `login' for #<UserSession: no credentials provided>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to setup Authlogic for my Rails3 project. In the user_sessions#new view, I keep getting the following error:

```
undefined method `login' for #<UserSession: no credentials provided>
Extracted source (around line #7):

5:   <%= form_for(:user_session, :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
6:     <%= f.label :login %><br>
7:     <%= f.text_field :login %><br>
8:     <%= f.password_field(:password) %>   
9:     <%= f.submit %>
10:   <% end %>
```

I believe that the error is coming because Authlogic is failing to detect which database column should be used for the login field.

I was under the understanding that Authlogic is supposed to fall back on the :email column if no login column is present. For belt and braces I tried adding a config option to the User class but it still did not solve the problem

Here is my code:

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.login_field = :email
  end
end
```

**UserSessions controller**

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController  
  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  # ...
end
```

**UserSessions#new view**

```
<%= form_for(:user_session, :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :login %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :login %><br>
  <%= f.password_field(:password) %>   
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**UserSession model**

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
   # configuration here, see documentation for sub modules of Authlogic::Session
end
```

**DB Schema (for authlogic tables)**

```
create_table "sessions", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "session_id", :null => false
  t.text     "data"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "sessions", ["session_id"], :name => "index_sessions_on_session_id"
add_index "sessions", ["updated_at"], :name => "index_sessions_on_updated_at"

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "crypted_password"
  t.string   "password_salt"
  t.string   "persistence_token"
end
```

Why won't Authlogic use the login column I tell it to (or is this even the problem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're telling AuthLogic to use the `email` field, but then using the `login` field in your view instead. Change your view to:

```
<%= form_for(:user_session, :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :email %><br>
  <%= f.password_field(:password) %>   
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and it should work.

Comment: Ugh - thank you! I had spent so long trying to figure it out and yet such as simple fix!

Answer (score 1):

This error can actually occur for multiple reasons.  The one that affects me most often is NOT having the users table created.